# Prove that any proper map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is unbounded.

Tags: general-topology

> **Problem:**
>
> A continous map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is called proper if $f^{-1}(C)$
>   is compact for any compact set $C \subset Y$.
>
> Prove that any proper map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is unbounded.

---

**Solution:**

The closure of the image $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not compact,

otherwise its preimage should be compact since $f$ is proper,

but the preimage is $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is non-compact.

Thus the closure is unbounded, so is also  $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ itself.

---

Is this solution acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is fine